# How to describe a data structure?

Tags: javascript

*This question had troubled me for a long time that I don't know how to describe a complicated data structure when I writing a API document or a code comment.*

For example, if I want to describe an array which included some numbers, maybe I could describe it like: `Array<Number>`. But what if I want to describe an object-array like `[{ id: Number, label: String }]`, or more crazy like

```
[{ 
    id: Number, 
    label: String, 
    anObj: {
        aDate: Date,
        aRegExp: RegExp
    }
}]
```

So is there any popular specification that I can describe it in a elegant way?

Comment: That question isn't for SO, but you can check out here: https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/advanced-tutorial.html

Comment: [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/)? But yes, any type system that can annotate JS expressions will do.

Answer (score 0):

I have used JSDoc [@param](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html) for these sort of descriptions. The same nesting rules used with a [@typedef](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) are just as readable. Here is an example:

```
    /**
     * ordered list of the most successfull games
     * @typedef {Object} ScoreRecorder~List
     * 
     * @property {Object[]} list - at most {@link options options.list.length} items
     * 
     *   @property {string | Date} list[].timestamp - formatted as LocaleDate or raw
     *   @property {ScoreRecorder~FormatedDuration | number} list[].score - time
     *   elapsed (formatted or number of seconds) or counter result
     *   @property {string} [list[].player=options.list.unknown] - only present if
     *   {@link options options.list.naming} has been set
     * 
     * @property {number} current - 1-based rank of the last successfull
     * game. 0 if not in the highscore list. Raw value conforms to Array.indexOf().
     */
```

Whether you can use it with a renderer like [jsdoc-to-markdown](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown) might be a bit hit-and-miss. The above example was converted to markdown like this (and it took some amount of tweaking to get there):

#### ScoreRecorder~List : `Object`

ordered list of the most successfull games

**Kind**: inner typedef of `ScoreRecorder`
**Properties**

- list `Array.<Object>` - at most
  options.list.length items
- list[].timestamp `string` | `Date` - formatted as LocaleDate or raw
- list[].score `FormatedDuration` | `number` - time
  elapsed (formatted or number of seconds) or counter result
- list[].player `string` - only present if
  options.list.naming has been set
- current `number` - 1-based rank of the last successfull
  game. 0 if not in the highscore list. Raw value conforms to Array.indexOf().